# php5-mongo and pecl mongo-stable

Tags: php, mongodb, debian, pecl

Do I need to get the debian package "php5-mongo" if I've already successfully installed mongoDB using PECL? What's the difference?
(and should this question be migrated?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the same difference as installing a perl module from CPAN, or a debian (or other OS) package. Its more a matter of preference, or who has the most up to date version.

Generally speaking, I prefer to install my perl modules through CPAN, and my php modules through PECL as opposed to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't make much difference unless your debian version of the driver is less than 1.0.11